# Devanagari (combined) words are not displaying correctly

Tags: fonts, printing, unicode, trisquel

I use Trisquel 7.0 LTS with GNOME 3 Flashback installed.

Combined [devanagari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari) fonts like: **श्री** is not displaying (and hence printing) correctly.

Example- The latter **should be displayed** as follows:

1. [image]
2. [image]

But **currently displaying** as follows:

1. [image]
2. [image]

So, how do I fix it?

I am facing this problem in every text fields such as: text-editor, LibreOffice, web-browser etc except with pdf.

Rarely it displays correctly in web-page but when I copy and paste it to gedit or libreoffice, facing mentioned problem.

Ask me if any information required to be provided with question in order to analyse and fix this issue.

Comment: Browsers, Gnome/Gtk apps like Gedit, and LibreOffice use three different font processing stacks. This isn't a single issue. That being said having the latest fontconfig, Harfbuzz, and Graphite libraries installed is a good place to start. Can you tell us what versions of those as well as LibreOffice you are running. Also what font are you testing with?

Comment: @Caleb LibreOffice Version:4.2.6.3 & Gedit Version:3.10.4. Changing/applying fonts doesn't affect it (try "श्री",mentioned in 1st line) ; LibreOffice shows language Hindi at bottom/status bar. Changing language also not affecting however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to install appropriate font package to the system which is **`ttf-devanagari-fonts`** here. (You can [search](http://packages.trisquel.info/search?keywords=devanagari&searchon=names&suite=belenos&section=all) on repository).

```
ttf-devanagari-fonts - Free TrueType fonts for languages using the Devanagari script
```

Package Description:

> Description: Free TrueType fonts for languages using the Devanagari script Fonts for languages that use the Devanagari script in writing. This package has fonts for Hindi, Kashmiri, Konkani, Marathi, Maithili, Nepali, Sanskrit, and Sindhi languages.

So, `sudo apt-get install ttf-devanagari-fonts` installs the devanagari fonts:

```
$ ls /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-devanagari-fonts/
chandas1-2.ttf  lohit_kok.ttf  lohit_mai.ttf  lohit_ne.ttf  nakula.ttf    samanata.ttf           Sarai_07.ttf
kalimati.ttf    lohit_ks.ttf   lohit_mr.ttf   lohit_sd.ttf  sahadeva.ttf  Samyak-Devanagari.ttf
```

Now, Devanagari fonts are displaying correctly.

---

**Update**: For the latest current (LTS) version of Trisquel GNU Linux i.e 8.0 Flidas, install the following package:

```
$ apt-cache search fonts-deva
fonts-deva - Meta package to install all Devanagari fonts
fonts-deva-extra - Free fonts for Devanagari script
```

And then set Lohit Devanagari by creating following configuration file as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/855811/256099):

```
$ cat .config/fontconfig/conf.d/10-prefer-devanagari.conf 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
        <alias>
                <family>serif</family>
                <prefer>
                        <family>Lohit Devanagari</family>
                </prefer>
        </alias>
        <alias>
                <family>sans-serif</family>
                <prefer>
                        <family>Lohit Devanagari</family>
                </prefer>
        </alias>
        <alias>
                <family>monospace</family>
                <prefer>
                        <family>Lohit Devanagari</family>


</prefer>
    </alias>
```

Logout and re-login to get the effect.

Answer (score 1):

You could also give it try to new **Google Noto fonts** they are amazing. Download them from the link and then.

**Goto Home Directory> press ctrl + h(if your files are hidden)**  then create a folder **.fonts** (if not already present) then just paste the fonts you downloaded.

Google Noto Font [Link.](https://www.google.com/get/noto/)