# Proper Devanagari (Sanskrit) ligatures in Terminal (Arch-based System)

Tags: arch-linux, terminal, fonts

My terminal is not able to display complex Devanagari (Sanskrit) ligatures properly. It is able to display the letters and certain ligatures, but not the complex ones. Similar as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245116/devanagari-combined-words-are-not-displaying-correctly), [here](https://super-unix.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-is-there-a-good-mono-spaced-font-for-devanagari-script-in-the-terminal/) or [here](https://super-unix.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-devnagari-script-in-terminal/). I tried the solutions described there.

I tested several terminals according to this list [here](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode#terminal-compatibility-list) but without success (konsole, kitty, tilix, mlterm etc). It seems that on certain distros is works well e.g. with gnome-terminal or konsole, but not on my distro (arch-based EndeavourOs, default xfce4-terminal).

Any suggestions for a optimal terminal and how to proper set up?

I work with vim, so a solution with a GUI I want to avoid. In gedit Editor the settings are perfect, but it's not my prefered solution.

Comment: Have you try to change the font? AFAIK ligatures are functions of font.

Comment: That was the hint I needed!

Answer (score 1):

I could solve it through Romeos input. I installed [Kitty](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/) which supports ligatures (with st terminal ligature-patch I was not successful). The nice thing in Kitty is, that you can map the specified Unicode codepoints to a particular font. I installed DejaVu Sans Mono which can display Devanagari characters as well as Latin characters.

XFCE is not able to display the complex ligatures even when I change to DejaVu Sans Mono fonts.

Answer (score 0):

This is not full answer as I have no idea how [ligatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligature_(writing)) in Sanskrit should looks like, but from my knowledge about fonts the ligatures is characteristic of fonts itself.

So try to change the font.

Comment: You where faster then me with the answer. I gave you an example link of an example of some ligatures [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245116/devanagari-combined-words-are-not-displaying-correctly)

Comment: I gave you an example link of some ligatures.

Comment: @Denis, for me ligatures are something I relate to desktop publishing and to have them in terminal is probably extra, extra bonus. But as you need them, have them should be standard (for you) :)